# converting cvmat to iplimage

Tags: opencv, iplimage

How can I convert a `cvMat` matrix to `IplImage` that can be saved using `cvSaveImage`, in C using OpenCV?

I learnt about a function `cvGetImage(const CvArr* arr, IplImage* imageHeader)`. I understand that `arr` stands for the `cvMat` Array, but could not really understand what 'image header' actually is. Is that the pointer that stores the image ?? That is, would the following work?

```
clusters = cvCreateMat( image2_size, 1, CV_32SC1 );
IplImage *kmeans;
cvGetImage(clusters, &kmeans);
cvSaveImage("kmeans.jpg", kmeans);
//clusters is the output matrix after performing k-means clustering
// on a certain image.
```

Comment: `cvSaveImage` can save `CvMat` without a conversion.